# Extra Back Button is visible in all screen in android

Tags: android

1)How do I delete the extra black arrow button? It shows in all pages. But the white arrow button is only in active state. When white button is pressed, it can go back.

[image]

2)How can I set the action bar with back button comes first followed with the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionBar actionBar= getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);`

try putting this at top inside your onCreate method,this will disable the default toolbar button of the app,then you can create your own toolbar and add it,but thats a whole other process,this answer would simply hide your icon and title which is coming automatically

Comment: For no title also add  :    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: Thnq for ur instant reply. As u said above, I wrongly put true in that method.. I have changed now. 
But it doesn't work. still black back btn is there. I need title with white arrow btn

Comment: then post you layout and java code,and try reinstalling the app

Comment: is this needed? 
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

Comment: if you wanna use the default icon then set it to true else set it to false

Comment: i saw your code , and what u need to do is simple go to your styles.xml file and

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: set ......NoActionBar will hide your default App bar , and then your custom toolbar can be user ....... and also remember to remove all the app bar related code you wrote after setting your toolbar

Comment: i.e everything u wrote below  etSupportActionBar(toolbar);  in your oncreate method

Answer (score 0):

I have enclosed my code..

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {     
        Toolbar toolbar;
                @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
                        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
                        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                }

                    public void showFragment(Fragment fragment, String back_stack_name, boolean isAddToBackStack) {
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
                        if (isAddToBackStack) {
                            transaction.addToBackStack(back_stack_name);
                        }
                        transaction.commit();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBackPressed() {
                        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                            showAlertDialog(Constants.EXIT_APP, Constants.APP_NAME);
                        } else {
                            getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                        }
                    }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/back_white"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/back_btn"
                android:contentDescription="Back" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_17sp"
                android:id="@+id/title_toolbar_txt"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```